# How do you make a digraph containing a ¨?

Tags: digraphs

When making a digraph, I can't seem use the `¨` symbol without getting an `E39: Number expected`. This error is there even when escaping it with a backslash.

Comment: What keys are you entering *exactly*?

Comment: Is your 'encoding' multibyte? `:digraphs` appears to want two bytes rather than two characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it output a ¨ by putting `168` as the output symbol, i.e. with, say, `:dig um 168`, but not use inside a digraph itself (`:dig a\168 228` still wont make `<c-k>a¨` output ä.)

Even the predefined digraphs use `:` instead; e.g. `<c-k>a:` give you ä.

Answer (score 1):

If the digraph has a code point (usually found by a web search for `unicode <character description>`), you can just use `<c-v>u####` to directly enter it.  For example `<c-v>u00e4` yields ä.

This does assume your editor can interpret the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The [`unicode.vim`](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) has a very useful `:UnicodeSearch` command. e.g. `:UnicodeSearch smile`. I think it also includes some useful digraph functions that may be helpful here (but I don't use digraphs do I'm not too familiar with it).

Comment: That's an interesting project.  I'll have to take a closer look when I have some down time.  I normally use Unicode for the super and subscripts, but occasionally I'll need the digraphs for author names.